# Responsive a static block - Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, rwd, slider

I was able to create full width sliders on a single page using custom css added to the design tab for the page:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/fullwidth.css</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

However, static blocks added to that page ignore this and are not responsive. Anybody have any ideas on this?

> https://www.staging.jewelsbygrace.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **@media queries** on you CSS to making responsive.

Answer (score 0):

1- Firstly Check if you have correctly loaded your `fullwidth.css` to do this open the source code of your website and search `fullwidth.css` If you find it, check if you have the right path to your file, however if you don't find it it means that your file is not loaded and of course it doesn't work.

To add a css file:
in **local.xml**

```
<default>
  <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fullwith.css</name></action>
  </reference>
<default>
```

2- you can put do your slider on fullwith and responsive using **Bootstrap**

Forexemple:

```
<div class="container-fluid">  //fullwith container
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        //here your slider code
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked for me!
 
1- Firstly Check if you have correctly loaded your fullwidth.css to do this open the source code of your website and search fullwidth.css If you find it, check if you have the right path to your file, however if you don't find it it means that your file is not loaded and of course it doesn't work.

To add a css file: in local.xml

  <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fullwith.css</name></action>
  </reference>

Comment: So if this is worked for you, please accept the answer.